# How do I make the right table have priority over the top table?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the right table have priority over the top table?

I want the table on the right (the pink one) to go all the up to the top of the web page.  And I want the top yellow table to end where the pink one starts on the right side of the screen?  Link to what Im talking about:

http://wpiix10.x10.mx/ifoot11.htm

And here's the code I'm using:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0" bgcolor="#00FF00" height="23" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
            <!-- MSTableType="nolayout" -->
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div align="right" style="height: 100%;">

            <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFF00" height="105">
                <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table border="0" width="200" align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FF00FF" height="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you have to display, you should use only divs instead of tables. They're easier to dispatch on your page, making them going over an other element etc.

If you still want to use tables (sic), in your present case you should use only one table.